Using Aplot to align a ggtree with a ggridges ridgeline?
I can't seem to get Aplot to correctly align a ggtree with a ggridges ridegeline plot / joy plot. The resulting plot shows the tree and a space for the ridges, but no ridges.
Here's a minimal example:
library(ggtree)
library(ggridges)
library(aplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Generate a minimal example phylogenetic tree
tree <- rtree(3)  # A small tree with 3 tips

# Plot the phylogenetic tree
p_tree <- ggtree(tree) + theme_tree()

# Generate minimal example data for the ridgeline plot
set.seed(123)
tip_labels <- tree$tip.label
data <- data.frame(
  label = rep(tip_labels, each = 50),
  value = unlist(lapply(tip_labels, function(x) rnorm(50, mean = which(tip_labels == x))))
)

# Compute density for each group
density_data <- data %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  do({
    dens <- density(.$value)
    data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)
  }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(y = y * 1000)  # Rescale y for better visibility

# Create the ridgeline plot
p_ridges <- ggplot(density_data, aes(x = x, y = label, height = y, fill = label)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity", scale = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  theme_ridges() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Combine the plots using aplot's insert_right
aligned_plot <- insert_right(p_tree, p_ridges, width = 1.5)

# Display the combined plot
print(aligned_plot)

which outputs the following plots:



I've printed all the intermediate steps. Alternatives to aplot, such as cowplot and patchwork, can't align the ridge lines to the tree like I'd like.

Looks like a bug or an incompatibilty with grudges.
As workaround you can use patchwork directly to align your tree and the ridgeline density plot instead of relying on aplot. The only tricky part is setting the expansion of the y scale for the tree plot right to align it with the density plot.
As the ridgeline plot has a discrete scale I use the default .6 at the lower end. For the upper end we have to do some manual computation, i.e. the scale is expanded to account for the maximum density of the density shown at the top. To get this maximum value I use layer_data and finally subtract 3, i.e. the number of categories.
Note: I added a theme_ridges to the patch to show more clearly that the plots align. You can simply drop the last line.
set.seed(1)

library(patchwork)

expand <- max(layer_data(p_ridges)$ymax) - 3

p_tree <- p_tree +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, .6, 0, expand))
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.

p_tree + p_ridges +
  plot_layout(widths = c(1, 1.5)) &
  theme_ridges()


